# Destroy not destroying instances of GameObject

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to create a script that places and removes tiles from around the player as they move around. I cannot use a static image as eventually I will be using noise to get a tile type for each coordinate, so as the player returns to an area, it looks the same.

As a chunk of tiles goes out of the render range, I'm calling `Destroy()` on each of instance of the `grassTile` `GameObject`, but they're not disappearing from the screen. I've read similar questions on here, but they all seem to be from people calling `Destroy()` on something other than the `GameObject`'s, which I'm confident I'm not doing. My best guess is that somewhere I'm cloning the instances of `grassTile` and not deleting the original instances that I can see on screen. I've tried `DestroyImmediate()` as well with no luck.

Here is the code:

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Unity.Collections;
using Unity.VisualScripting;
using UnityEditor.SearchService;
using UnityEngine;

public class TileManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Objects & Variables
    public int chunkRadius = 1;
    public int renderRadius = 1;

    public GameObject grassTile;
    public GameObject background;
    public GameObject player;
    
    private Vector2 playerPosition => player.transform.position;
    private Dictionary<Vector2, GameObject[]> chunks = new Dictionary<Vector2, GameObject[]>();
    private int chunkWidth;

    // Unity Functions

    void Awake() {
        chunkWidth = 1 + 2 * chunkRadius;
        DrawChunk(GetChunkPlayerIsIn());
    }

    void Update() {
        foreach(Vector2 chunk in GetChunksToDraw()){
            DrawChunk(chunk);
        }

        Debug.Log($"Destroying {GetChunksToDestroy().Count} chunks");
        foreach(Vector2 chunk in GetChunksToDestroy()){
            DestroyChunk(chunk);
        }
    }

    // Private Functions

    private List<Vector2> GetChunksToDraw(){
        List<Vector2> chunksToDraw = new List<Vector2>();
        Vector2 playerChunk = GetChunkPlayerIsIn();
        int minX = (int)playerChunk.x - renderRadius * chunkWidth;
        int maxX = (int)playerChunk.x + renderRadius * chunkWidth;
        int minY = (int)playerChunk.y - renderRadius * chunkWidth;
        int maxY = (int)playerChunk.y + renderRadius * chunkWidth;

        for(int x = minX; x <= maxX; x += chunkWidth){
            for (int y = minY; y <= maxY; y += chunkWidth){
                Vector2 center = new Vector2(x, y);
                if(!chunks.ContainsKey(center)){
                    chunksToDraw.Add(center);
                }
            }
        }

        return chunksToDraw;
    }

    private List<Vector2> GetChunksToDestroy(){
        List<Vector2> chunksToDestroy = new List<Vector2>();
        foreach(Vector2 chunk in chunks.Keys){
            float distance = Mathf.Abs((chunk - playerPosition).magnitude);
            if(distance > chunkWidth){
                Debug.Log($"Destroying chunk {chunk} that is {distance} away");
                chunksToDestroy.Add(chunk);
            }
        }

        return chunksToDestroy;
    }

    private Vector2 GetChunkPlayerIsIn(){
        float nearestX = Mathf.Abs(playerPosition.x) + chunkRadius / 2f;
        nearestX -= nearestX % chunkRadius;
        nearestX *= playerPosition.x > 0 ? 1 : -1;

        float nearestY = Mathf.Abs(playerPosition.y) + chunkRadius / 2f;
        nearestY -= nearestY % chunkRadius;
        nearestY *= playerPosition.y > 0 ? 1 : -1;

        return new Vector2(nearestX, nearestY);
    }

    private void DrawChunk(Vector2 center) {
        int minX = Mathf.FloorToInt(center.x) - chunkRadius;
        int maxX = Mathf.FloorToInt(center.x) + chunkRadius;
        int minY = Mathf.FloorToInt(center.y) - chunkRadius;
        int maxY = Mathf.FloorToInt(center.y) + chunkRadius;

        GameObject[] tiles = new GameObject[(int)Mathf.Pow(1 + 2 * chunkRadius, 2)];
        for(int x = minX; x <= maxX; x++){
            for(int y = minY; y <= maxY; y++){
                GameObject tile = Instantiate(grassTile, background.transform);
                tile.transform.position = new Vector2(x, y);
                tiles.Append(tile);
            }
        }

        chunks.Add(center, tiles);
    }

    private void DestroyChunk(Vector2 chunk) {
        for(int i = 0; i < chunks[chunk].Count(); i++){
            Destroy(chunks[chunk][i]);
        }

        chunks.Remove(chunk);
    }
}
```

Update:

Thanks for your comments! Since asking this I've done some more debugging and I've found that the instances of the `grassTile` prefab are becoming null after adding them to the array. I wrote this barebones code to show the issue:

```cs
    // Objects & Variables
    public static TerrainManager instance;

    public GameObject grassTilePrefab;
    private GameObject[] grassTiles = new GameObject[1];
    private int lifeTime = 100;

    // Unity Functions

    void Start(){
        if (instance == null) instance = this;
        else Destroy(gameObject);
        
        grassTiles.Append(Instantiate(grassTilePrefab));
    }

    void Update(){
        --lifeTime;
        if(lifeTime <= 0){
            Destroy(grassTiles[0]);
        }
    }
```

With this code, the `grassTilePrefab` is instantiated, but never disappears. Even if the class isn't a singleton, this code does not work.

For this code, the `grassTile` game object is correctly destroyed:

```cs
// Objects & Variables
    public static TerrainManager instance;

    public GameObject grassTilePrefab;
    private GameObject grassTile;
    private int lifeTime = 100;

    // Unity Functions

    void Start(){
        if (instance == null) instance = this;
        else Destroy(gameObject);
        
        grassTile = Instantiate(grassTilePrefab);
    }

    void Update(){
        --lifeTime;
        if(lifeTime <= 0){
            Destroy(grassTile);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Have you considered: Maybe the `Vector2` isn't a good candidate as a key in the Dictionary since it might be slightly off ( => I would rather use `Vector2Int` as a key) and - not causing an issue but performance question - why use `Count()` instead of `Length`? In general [**Debug your code!**](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ManagedCodeDebugging.html) this is the best way for finding out what is going wrong and where and why exactly rather than having us stare at your code and try to figure it out in our head ;)

Comment: Also how do you make sure that multiple tiles do not maybe overlap?

Comment: Another more performance/efficiency related comment: You shouldn't use and pass around all those `List` instances and in particular **every frame** allocate new ones ... instead rather do e.g. `var sqrWidth = chunkWidth * chunkWidth; foreach(var chunk in chunks.Keys.ToList()){ if(Mathf.Abs(chunk - playPosition).sqrMagnitude > sqrWidth) { if(chunks.Remove(chunk, out var tiles)) { foreach(var tile in tiles) { Destryo(tile); } } } }` .. in general you might want to look into [Object Pooling](https://learn.unity.com/tutorial/introduction-to-object-pooling) as well